# Is it easy to factorize a number of the form $n = t^{2} \cdotp p$?

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring

Is it easy to factorize a number of the form $n = t^{2} \cdotp p$, where $t$ and $p$ are large primes?

Comment: As far as I know, this is an open problem. It's been conjectured that numbers of this form can be factored much more efficiently. However, no algorithm has been demonstrated.

Comment: If it were easy, it would immediately and completely break the ESIGN signature scheme [(section 11.7.2 of the Handbook of Applied Crypto PDF)](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap11.pdf)

Comment: It is not known to be easy in general, but [in some cases it can be](ftp://ftp.di.ens.fr/pub/users/pnguyen/Asia09.pdf).

Comment: @SamuelNeves, that would be a good answer, especially with a choice quote or two from the paper.

Comment: If feasible, it would also break the Okamoto Uchiyama homomorphic encryption scheme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integers of the form $n = p\cdot q^2$, $p$ and $q$ prime, are the basis of a few public-key cryptosystems, including [ESIGN](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-46416-6_38), [Okamoto-Uchiyama](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0054135), cryptosystems based around the [hardness of finding the class number of quadratic fields](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02351719). As such, being able to efficiently factor numbers of this form would immediately break a number of cryptosystems. This would be a big deal. Additionally, this is also related to a classic problem in number theory, which would be of independent interest.

As far as concrete factorization algorithms targeting this type of integers, there are various strands:

- [Peralta and Okamoto](http://www.cs.yale.edu/~peralta/papers/SpeedEcm.ps) slightly optimized ECM against this form, but the result is not significantly superior to regular ECM.
- [Boneh, Durfee, and Howgrave-Graham](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/prq.html) used Coppersmith-style root-finding techniques to factor $n$ in approximately $n^{1/9}$ operations when $p$ and $q$ are similarly-sized. While this may sound impressive, it is not better than the number field sieve for numbers of cryptographically-relevant size.
- [Castagnos, Joux, Laguillaumie, and Nguyen](https://www.di.ens.fr/~pnguyen/pub_CJLN09.htm) observed that, given some extra information about $n$ it becomes possible to factor $n$ in polynomial time. But this is not the general case and only applies to special cases, like [NICE](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-48059-5_28).